# 2 qubits, correct way CNOT a 3rd qubit with the 1st?

Tags: quantum-computing, linear-algebra

Suppose I have 2 qubits in the state a|00>+b|01>+c|10>+d|11>.  And suppose I want to perform some operation between only the 1st qubit and a 3rd qubit - for example a CNOT operation.  What would be the correct way to do this multiplication?

Comment: What do you mean by the correct way to do this?  What kind of answer are you looking for -- a matrix, an algorithm, a description of a physical computer, something else?  What approaches have you considered?

Comment: A matrix and process I suppose.  I know I could make matrix and fill it in with I for the qubit I don't want to affect and CNOT (just for example) for the qubit I do want to affect.  But this would require a 2^3 X 2^3 matrix.  This is fine for small numbers of qubits, but I don't see how this could work with large numbers of qubits (say 50).  50 qubits would require a 2^50 X 2^50 matrix which is too large of a matrix to work with for a computer.  So I'm trying to understand how mathematically to apply operations to specific qubits without invoke some huge (ie 2^50 X 2^50) matrix.

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48834/755.  Please see the explanations there and edit the question if there is some distinction that I missed.  As far as 50 qubits requiring a 2^50 x 2^50 matrix, please see http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48781/755.  I sympathize with your feelings of discomfort about such large matrices, but I don't see what else there is to say than what was written there -- yes such a quantum process is modelled by a 2^50 x 2^50 matrix, but the matrix is just a mathematical construct.  Large matrix != unrealizable in practice.